# How to fire event submit and get value form group with updateOn submit option angular?

Tags: angular, forms

I have a `formGroup` with multiple `formControl`. Because I want to improve performance and don't want to show errors when I input or change value of `formControl`, so I use `'updateOn': 'submit'` option so that I will update value when I submit form. But in the form, I have two buttons, that will save the form value for two purposes. Therefore, I can't use (submit) events in the HTML template.

Is there any way to fire event submit and get value immediately? Or can you suggest me what the better solution for this case?

```
<form [formGroup]="accountForm" #f="form">
   <button (click)="submitCreateAccount()">Create</button>
   <button (click)="submitSaveToTemp()">Save Draft</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what value are you expecting to get? what is this 'updateOn': 'submit' option you are talking? Can you share a little bit more of the form?

Comment: I had updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would use `updateOn submit`. Instead like you have, two different functions for 2 different cases.

Buttons inside forms are by default of type `submit`. If you want different actions for the buttons, add `type="button"` to the one you don't want to fire the submit function.
So if you want "Save draft" button to not fire the submit function do:

```
<button (click)="submitSaveToTemp()" type="button">Save Draft</button>
```

... or the other way around. Or then both can be of `type` button. But the other one can very well be of type `submit` as I see it. In both cases you can though access the form values with `this.accountForm.value`.

Comment: I use `updateOn submit` because I have a form with multiple formControl, and I don't want to show errors when I input or change formControl, it will make the UI inefficient and low performance. I have tried using this.accountForm.value but it will return the old value. If using event `(ngSubmit)` or `(submit)` in the `<form>` tag, it will update new value of form. But in this case, I have two actions. You can suggest for me what should I do in this case?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. I wouldn't worry about the performance, it is not a deal breaker here, rather get the functionality you want. You can also always change when to show error messages. If you want to only show them on submit, then add a boolean flag that you switch to true (and show error messages) when you click submit button.

Comment: Currently, I have implemented that your suggestion. I think it will better for me from now. Thank you for your support :))

Answer (score 0):

This code solves your requirements. You can get your form data -

```
submitCreateAccount() {
    console.log(this.accountForm.value);
}
```

Comment: using this.accountForm.value, it will return old value at this time